# zum + noun oder zu + verb

Tags: infinitive

Ich habe zwei Alternativen gesehen:

- Letztes Mal hatten wir nicht viel Zeit zum Reden.
- Leztes Mal hatten wir nicht viel Zeit, zu reden.

Es gibt einen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen beiden? 
Es scheint mir, dass Deutsch normalerweise die erste Form bevorzugt. Stimmt das?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beide Varianten sind gebräuchlich, der Infinitivsatz aber eigentlich nur dann, wenn weitere Informationen hinzukommen:

> Letztes Mal hatten wir nicht viel Zeit zum Reden. *(gebräuchlich)*
>
> Letztes Mal hatten wir nicht viel Zeit(,) zu reden. *(weniger gebräuchlich)*
>
> Letztes Mal hatten wir nicht viel Zeit zum Reden über das Projekt. *(weniger gebräuchlich)*
>
> Letztes Mal hatten wir nicht viel Zeit, (um) über das Projekt zu reden. *(gebräuchlich)*